# Elasticsearch 7.x enrich processor missing few documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to enrich an index by data from another index.
In my `address-index` (source index) I have two fields `address` and `locationCode`.

```
address-index: 
{
   "locationCode" : "ABC",
   "address" : "xxx, NC,USA"
},
{
   "locationCode" : "XYZ",
   "address" : "xxxx, OK,USA"
}
```

In my `employee-index` (destination index) I will be having `location` based on that I need to enrich the `address`

```
employee-index: 
{
   "location" : "ABC"
},
{
   "location" : "XYZ"
}
```

Im trying to achieve this using enrich pipeline

I have created the policy like below

```
PUT /_enrich/policy/location-address-policy
{
  "match": {
    "indices": "address-index",
    "match_field": "locationCode",
    "enrich_fields": ["address"]
  }
}
PUT /_enrich/policy/location-address-policy/_execute
```

I have pipeline as below

```
[
  {
    "enrich": {
      "description": "Add 'address' based on 'location'",
      "policy_name": "location-address-policy",
      "field": "location",
      "target_field": "location_enriched",
      "ignore_missing": true,
      "override": false,
      "max_matches": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "rename": {
      "description": "Creates field address from nested field location_enriched.address",
      "field": "location_enriched.address",
      "target_field": "address",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  },
  {
    "remove": {
      "description": "Removes field location_enriched generated from 'enrich' step ",
      "field": "location_enriched",
      "ignore_missing": true
    }
  }
]
```

The few documents are updating well and few are not. For example Few documents with location `ABC` are enriched with `"address" : "xxx, NC,USA"` and few dont have address field at all. What could be the reason?

Comment: can you try `_simulate` pipeline [api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/simulate-pipeline-api.html) and pass document which are not updating to `docs`. you will be able to debug or check output of specific document.

Comment: @SagarPatel with the help of simulate i observed that, in the enrich section the target_field (location_enriched) doesn't contain enrich_fields (address) for few documents.